# Calculating cov_matrix using specific dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, covariance

I have a dataframe like this:

[image: dataframe]

`Ticker` means `Stock Name` and I've calculated `pct_change` and now I need to calculate `cov matrix` for each Ticker = StockName.

Output should look similar to that:

[image: output]

Any ideas how to calculate matrix like above for my column `pct_change`??

I've started from this code and my next step is to calculate covariance.

```
import pandas as pd

import glob
import os

os.chdir('C:\\Users\xxxxx')
files_list = glob.glob('*.txt')
stocks = {}

for i, file in enumerate(files_list):
    stocks[i] = pd.read_csv(files_list[i], names=['Ticker', 'Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Vol'], 
                            header=None).drop(index=0).reset_index().drop(columns='index')
    stocks[i].iloc[:, stocks[i].columns.get_loc('Open'):] = stocks[i].iloc[:, stocks[i].columns.get_loc('Open'):].astype('float')
    stocks[i]['pct_change'] = stocks[i]['Close'].pct_change()
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some fake data that mimics the characteristics of your data - panel data with ticker-date as the unique observation identifer.

```
df
```

[image]

What I did was pivot the data like so

```
dfp = df.pivot(index='date',columns='ticker',values='pct_change')
dfp
```

[image]

Now I can use Numpy's covariance matrix function.

```
cov = np.cov(df.values)
cov
```

[image]